# Json и вывод данных

Tags: php, json

считываю json через php, но иногда данные исчезают(иногда записываются в файл) и появляется ошибка:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$deg

Так как его не существует как можно сделать сравнение, если запись со значением `$deg` в json файле исчезнет или наоборот появится, пробовал сравнивать с `null` но не проходит, так как `$deg` вообще отсутствует

Comment: `isset()` ? `empty()`?

Comment: Большое спасибо